# How can I delete my own node comments?

Tags: 7, comments

How can I delete my own node comments without installing modules?

Googling, I found the [Comment Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/commentaccess) module. I don't want to install it.

Comment: you should be able to delete own comments as long as you have permission.

Comment: Could be your theme, try switching to a Drupal core theme and see if you can see the delete button link.

Comment: @NoSssweat, AFAIK there is no way to give the permission to delete *own* comment to a user without installing a module.

Answer (score 1):

There is no permission in a default D7 configuration to only delete one's *own* comment. To get this you must install [Comment Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/commentaccess) (or another contributed module with a similar function).

If you add the permission "Administer comments and comment settings" (navigate to *Administration » People » Permissions*), to a role, that role get access to a "Delete" tab for comments, but that lets the user holding this permission delete *everbody's* comments - not only his/her own.

Installing a module is no big deal in Drupal.  If you want this, I am afraid you need to install a module.

Comment: I was just going to post same reply, "Comment Access" ... :)